# Jquery paste html to multiple textareas and span with same class

Tags: jquery

I have HTML where multiple textareas and span share same class:

```
<textarea class="abc"></textarea>
<span class="abc"></span>
```

I want that if I change html in any one of these element the changes should reflect in all elements.

I tried with this:

```
$(document).on('input', '.abc', function(event) {
    x = $(this).html();
    $('.abc').each(function(index, el) {
        $(this).html(x);
    });
});
```

But this is not working. How can I do this?

Comment: What is `.lat1` ?

Comment: If your selector is a class it will affect anything with that class.

Comment: Yes. I have many classes and more that 10 elements for each classes in a large form. I just want that changes made in 1 span or textarea should reflect in all elements with same class

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced `.html()` with `.val()` for getting textarea value. Also the original post had `.lat1` instead of `.abc` as a selector and replaced that too. User changed it in his question after I did:

```js
$(document).on('input', '.abc', function(event) {
    var x = $(this).val();
    $('.abc').each(function(index, el) {
        $(this).html(x);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="abc"></textarea>
<span class="abc"></span>
```

If you have multiple elements and need to change them one by one you can do it like this:

```js
$(document).on('input', '.abc', function(event) {
  var x = $(this).val();
    $(this).next('.abc').html(x);
});
```

```css
.abc{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="abc"></textarea>
<span class="abc"></span>

<textarea class="abc"></textarea>
<span class="abc"></span>

<textarea class="abc"></textarea>
<span class="abc"></span>
```

Comment: No it doesn't. I've also changed `.html()` with `.val()`. So don't be so quick to downvote please.

Comment: I was just testing in a fiddle with on change. And I forgot to add back the `input` event. It should work with both on `change` and `input`. I've changed the `.html()` with `.val()` as he can type in the textarea and wants to get the value from there. `.html()` does not work for textarea's.

Comment: @isherwood, is my answer now what you expect?

Comment: See my answer below, no need for each, simply select the class (uses jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
      $('.abc').html('Changed');
  });
  
  $('button.reset').click(function(){
    $('.abc').html('Change this text');
    });
});
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="abc">Change this text</textarea>
<span class="abc">Change this text</span>
<textarea class="abc">Change this text</textarea>
<span class="abc">Change this text</span>
<textarea class="abc">Change this text</textarea>
<span class="abc">Change this text</span>
<textarea class="abc">Change this text</textarea>
<span class="abc">Change this text</span>
<button>Click this</button>
<button class="reset">Reset</button>
```

Here's what I'm discussing, you can select all of that class and manipulate them all at the same time.